# groupby and stack column into a single column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product' : ['A'], 
              'Size' : ["['XL','L','S','M']"],
               'Color' : ["['Blue','Red','Green']"]})

print(df)

Product                Size                   Color
0       A  ['XL','L','S','M']  ['Blue','Red','Green']
```

I need to transform the frame for an ingestion system which only accepts the following format:

```
target_df = pd.DataFrame({'Description' : ['Product','Color','Color','Color','Size','Size','Size','Size'],
             'Agg' : ['A','Blue','Green','Red','XL','L','S','M']})


  Description    Agg
0     Product      A
1       Color   Blue
2       Color  Green
3       Color    Red
4        Size     XL
5        Size      L
6        Size      S
7        Size      M
```

I've attempted all forms of explode, groupby and even itterrows, but I can't get it to line up. I have thousands of Products. with a few groupby and explodes I can stack the column but then I have duplicate Product Names which I need to avoid, the order is important too.

Comment: Just to be clear, inside your dataframe are strings? Also does your dataframe contain more than 1 row?

Comment: yes all strings and yes i have over 1k rows hence multiple products. the format is the same as above @QuangHoang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution without `eval`:

```
(df.T[0].str.strip('[]')
   .str.split(',', expand=True)
   .stack().str.strip("''")
   .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
   .rename_axis(index='Description')
   .reset_index(name='Agg')
)
```

Output:

```
  Description    Agg
0     Product      A
1        Size     XL
2        Size      L
3        Size      S
4        Size      M
5       Color   Blue
6       Color    Red
7       Color  Green
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
df['Size']=df['Size'].map(eval)
df['Color']=df['Color'].map(eval)
df=df.stack().explode()
```

Outputs:

```py
0  Product        A
   Size          XL
   Size           L
   Size           S
   Size           M
   Color       Blue
   Color        Red
   Color      Green
dtype: object
```

Comment: Had the same, but to match the expected output: `df.stack().explode().reset_index(level=1).rename(columns={"level_1":"Description", 0:"Agg"})`

Comment: I thought about it - but then OP mentioned there are multiple rows - which (IMO) means it should be somehow indicated. Leaving it that way it's quite clear how each line is defined. So I decided to put it in a format not necessarily as OP wanted, but more flexible for post-processing.

Answer (score 1):

Although both of the answers are already sufficient, thought this was one was nice to work out. Heres a method using `explode` and `melt`:

```
from ast import literal_eval
# needed, because somehow apply(literal_eval) wanst working
for col in df[['Size', 'Color']]:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(literal_eval)

dfn = df.explode('Size').reset_index(drop=True)
dfn['Color'] = df['Color'].explode().reset_index(drop=True).reindex(dfn.index)
dfn = dfn.melt(var_name='Description', value_name='Agg').ffill().drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)

  Description    Agg
0     Product      A
1        Size     XL
2        Size      L
3        Size      S
4        Size      M
5       Color   Blue
6       Color    Red
7       Color  Green
```

Comment: Thanks Erfan v. useful. I went with Quang's solution as it gave me flexibility. My bigger gripe is what ingestion system would want something like this.. but meh.